# Nginx docker-compose forward traffic to my backend services

Tags: docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have services running in docker-compose and i want to reverse proxy to them using nginx

How do I reach my backend service through the proxy, at the moment Nginx not passing my request on to backend. I also want to strip out the `/api/search` before the request reaches the backend service ([meilisearch](https://meilisearch.com/))

```
meilisearch    | [2022-07-11T14:00:02Z INFO  actix_server::server] Actix runtime found; starting in Actix runtime
nginx          | 172.25.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2022:14:00:09 +0000] "GET /api/search HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "insomnia/2022.4.2" "-"
nginx          | 2022/07/11 14:00:09 [error] 31#31: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.25.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /api/search/ HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
nginx          | 172.25.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2022:14:00:09 +0000] "GET /api/search/ HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "insomnia/2022.4.2" "-"
```

This is the `reverse_proxy.conf` file

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location /api/ {
        location /api/search/ {            
            proxy_pass http://meilisearch:7700; 
            rewrite ^/api/search(/.*) $1 last;           
        } 
    }       
}
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.0-alpine
    hostname: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      - safedawanetwork 
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./reverse_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  meilisearch:
    image: getmeili/meilisearch:v0.28.0rc4
    hostname: meilisearch
    container_name: meilisearch
    networks:
      - safedawanetwork       
networks:
    safedawanetwork:
        driver: bridge
```

When I start the services with `sudo docker-compose up` and `curl localhost/api/search` I expect to see the meilisearch response but I don't. Whats going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be doable just using a proxy pass that ends with a slash (/).
This works since nginx omits the matching part of the location block:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location /api/ {
        location /api/search/ {     
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://meilisearch:7700/;          
        } 
    }       
}
```

A request looking like: `curl localhost/api/search/test123`
will result in a request within your search service that ends up looking like this:

```
GET /test123 HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: eh, a slash ```/``` unbelievable

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout this [NGINX Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls)
tra
Based on the common mistakes, you shouldn't use a nested location in `/api` location here, so based some updates, you can try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://meilisearch:7700; 
        location /api/search/ {            
           rewrite ^/api/search(/.*) $1 last; 
        } 
    }  
}
```

However if you still have issues, let me know, so I can edit this answer and help you.

Comment: meilisearch is still getting the /api/search which causes a 404. ```meilisearch    | [2022-07-11T22:32:31Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 172.25.0.3 "GET /api/search HTTP/1.0" 404 0 "-" "insomnia/2022.4.2" 0.000041
nginx          | 172.25.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2022:22:32:31 +0000] "GET /api/search HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "insomnia/2022.4.2" "-```

Comment: Okay so create one location for each one, I mean  `location / { proxy_pass http://meilisearch:7700; }` ,  `location /api/search/ { rewrite ^/api/search(/.*) $1 last; }`

Comment: I cant put the meilisearch at the root path ```/``` because I want to add other services eg ````/api/search``` and ```/api/imagemanipulation``` without resorting to adding via new subdomains